# Benchmark Elasticsearch using Apache JMeter

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, jmeter, benchmarking

I am currently using the Apache JMeter tool for benchmarking Elasticsearch.
I am using Elasticsearch's BULK API for posting documents into my index and to measure the result.
Doing this manually with the HTTP Request and with the Body Data is working fine. However, I would like to that automatically. I saw that I can use the CSV Data Set Config Config Element where I can put the body data of the HTTP Request in a CSV file.
Basically, the BULK API requires to write the elements one below the other:

```
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"name": "John Doe" }
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"name": "Jane Doe" }
```

Finally, one request should have 1000 of index and name pairs. Above you see two. So the question is, how would you configure the CSV Data Set Config and the HTTP Request so that you have only one POST Request with 1000x index and name pairs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given your CSV payload looks like:

```
1, John Doe
2, Jane Doe
3, Someone Else
```

Configure your CSV Data Set config as follows:

[image: CSV Data Set Config]

And the relevant HTTP Request like:

[image: HTTP Request]

On each iteration and/or thread next value will be read and variables in the request will be substituted with the values from CSV

[image: CSV Demo]

Depending on what you're trying to achieve your CSV Data Set configuration might be different, see [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config) guide